# Настройка домашнего роутера

Tags: router, zte

Всем доброго времени суток, при пользовании роутером zxhn h118n обнаружилась интересная уязвимость: при логине superadmin и пароле Fn@ztE118zTE он заходит в настройки, независимо от установленного пароля. Есть ли какая-либо возможность исправить это?

Comment: Как вариант для попробовать, заходим через telnet на роутер под указанными вами данными, проверяем есть ли shell, если есть, пробуем командой `passwd` заменить пароль пользователя.

Comment: Функционал терминала ограничен ровно теми же функциями, что и в личном кабинете, хотя и похож на цисковский, но очень урезанный